# Fill NaN in specific row and column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this-

```
>>> df  
     a    d    s  
0  1.0  3.0  2.0  
1  2.0  NaN  4.0  
2  3.0  6.0  NaN  
3  NaN  NaN  3.0  
4  5.0  8.0  NaN  
5  6.0  NaN  NaN
```

I have to replace NaN with mean in column 'd' where value of column 'a' > 2. So, I write-

```
>>> df['d'][df['a']>2]  
2    6.0  
4    8.0  
5    NaN  

>>> df['d'][df['a']>2].fillna(df['d'][df['a']>2].mean(), inplace = True)
```

But this does not seem to work, it returns the same dataframe without affecting the NaN value in last row of 'd' column.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. I am using pandas version 0.21

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd need to assign to `loc`. First, compute the mean.

```
i = df.loc[df.a > 2, 'd'].mean()
```

Now, call `fillna` and assign it back.

```
df.loc[df.a > 2, 'd'] = df.loc[df.a > 2, 'd'].fillna(i)
df

     a    d    s
0  1.0  3.0  2.0
1  2.0  NaN  4.0
2  3.0  6.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  3.0
4  5.0  8.0  NaN
5  6.0  7.0  NaN    # <---
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Please tell me why have you not used **inplace = True** and also what was wrong with my approach?

Comment: @AnkitSeth You may use `inplace=True`, but it does not offer any performance/efficiency benefits over an assignment back. Furthermore, You were creating views and copies, so the `fillna` affects the copies, and not the original.

Comment: @AnkitSeth So, you can replace the condition with `(df.a > 2) & (df.s > 5)`. Note the brackets, you must enclose each condition in its parentheses.